# bootstrap toogle not working from 768 to 1320 screen width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want mynavbar to collapsed untill there is enough space for all li  to fit navbar .My navbar also has right aligned searchbar.

It works fine upto screen width of 767
from 768 to 1320, when clicked, opens and closes immediately.
Please help how to resolve this.
I also tried changing navbar-nav li a display to block; No use.
I am totally confused about this. How cant the navbar toggle not work after 768 when it works fine in less screen width.
Important: I am using multiple pages and copied the same navbar code on all pages with changing the active class.

```css
 .navbar {
                    /*background-color:#fff;*/
                    background: url(backdrop1.png) no-repeat;
                    background-size: cover;
                    min-height: 150px !important;
                    border-radius: 0;
                    margin-bottom: 0;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee !important;
                    z-index: 500;
                }

                .navbar-brand {
                    padding: 0 15px !important;
                    height: 150px;
                    line-height: 150px;
                }

                    .navbar-brand > img {
                        height: 100%;
                        padding: 15px 0;
                        width: auto;
                        margin: 0 auto;
                    }

                .navbar-collapse {
                    max-height: 100% !important;
                }

               .navbar-nav > li >a {
                    padding-top: 0px !important;
                    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
                    line-height: 150px;
                }
              #navform{
height:150px;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align : middle;
              }
                nav .navbar-toggle {
                    margin: 25px 15px 25px 0;
                    /*margin-top: 58px;
          padding: 9px 10px !important;*/
                }

                nav a {
                    font-weight: bold;
                    color: #186bac !important;
                    font-size: 16px;
                    transition: all 0.7s ease;
                }

                .navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav> .active > a {
                    color: #e54d1a !important;
                    background-color: transparent !important;
                }
                
                .dropdown-menu {
                    top:60%;
                    background-color: #BCD2EE !important;
                    color:#186bac;
                    
                }

                    .dropdown-menu li a {

                        color: #186bac !important;
                        background-color: #BCD2EE !important;
                        transition: all 0.7s ease;
                    }
                    .dropdown-menu li a:active, .dropdown>li>a {color:#e54d1a;}
                        .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
                            
                            color: #e54d1a !important;
                        }

                        .dropdown-menu li a:focus {
                            background-color: #4973AB !important;
                            color: White !important;
                        }

                        
                @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1320px) {
                    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
                        display: none !important;
                    }

                    .navbar-toggle {
                        display: block !important;
                        float: right;
                    }

                    .navbar-header {
                        float: none;
                    }
                }

                @media (max-width: 768px) {
                    #topbar {
                        display: none;
                    }

                    .navbar-brand {
                        height: 100px;
                    }

                    .navbar-nav > li > a {
                        line-height: 20px;
                        padding-top: 10px;
                        padding-bottom: 10px;
                    }
                }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="HomeNavbar">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="Index.html">


                    <img class="img-responsive" src="logo.png" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">



                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="Index.html">HOME</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">

                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="">
                            Menu1
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Menu1a</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                            Menu2
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="">Menu2a</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="">Menu2b</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                            Menu3
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="">Menu3a</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">Menu4</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                            Menu5
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Menu5a</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu5b</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <form class="navbar-form" action="/action_page.php" id="navform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
                                <div class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </li>

                </ul>



            </div>
        </div>

    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the following line,

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none !important;
}
```

under,

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1320px)
```

The collapsible is visible for a short time when the animation is running with 'collapsing' class and becomes hidden because of this rule once the animation ends.

In case of bootstrap 3:

You seem to have overriden a lot of their original behavior.
You need to pair,

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
display: none !important;
}
```

with,

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
display: block !important;
}
```

Read the classes description [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse) to understand why.

Comment: What should I do now...I removed it but the whole navbar is open

Comment: It's working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/grrakesh4769/aq9Laaew/170809/

Comment: I am really confused... the same code works different on my system. The nav li are place in a row not one below the other.

Comment: my fiddle is using bootstrap 4; what version are you using? Also check if there is any additional css or js

Comment: I am using bootstrap 3

Comment: My bad; Wrong link; Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/grrakesh4769/aq9Laaew/171354/